# How do I create a concatenated axis in python tsfresh for data visualization?

Tags: python, pandas, tsfresh

I’m trying to visualize a comparison between good_length_avg and bad_length_avg across length and widths.

But I get a key error on my created column Pallet

```
import pandas as pd
 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
from tsfresh import extract_features
 
df_avg_1['Pallet'] = df_avg_1['Pallet_Segment'].astype(str) + '-' + df_avg_1['Pallet_Width'].astype(str)
 
extracted_features = extract_features(df_avg_1, column_id='Pallet')
 
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
 
plt.scatter(extracted_features['Pallet'], extracted_features['bad_length_avg'], label='Bad Average')
 
plt.scatter(extracted_features['Pallet'], extracted_features['good_length_avg'], label='Good Average')
 
plt.xlabel('Pallet')
 
plt.ylabel('Average Value')
 
plt.title('Comparison of Good and Bad by Pallet')
 
plt.legend()
 
plt.show()
```